# Form Inputs & Labels in separate rows?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form:

```
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="firstname"/>

  <label for="">E-mail</label>
  <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="secondname"/>
</form>
```

And I would like to have all elements underneath another, that is, I would like to have it look like this:

> Name:
>    
> [Field]
>    
> E-mail:
>    
> [Field]

But right now, everything is just right next to each other - how would I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following css

```
 label { display:block }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `display: block` in css for each element you want on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'br' tag after each line in your code like this

```
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="firstname"/><br>

    <label for="">E-mail</label><br>
    <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="secondname"/>
</form>
```

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/shakil/pen/mWZOvM).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it.
first is this: use the tag `<br>`. It works like the button "enter" of the keyboard.

```
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label><br>
    <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="firstname"/>
    <br>
    <label for="">E-mail</label><br>
    <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="secondname"/>
</form>
```

Second is this: you can set the attribute called display to make it like a block element. like this:

```
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
<label>Name:</label><br>
<input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="firstname"/>
<br>
<label for="">E-mail</label><br>
<input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="secondname"/>
</form>
```

Comment: oh ,sorry ,It's my mistake.here is the right ont.                                           <form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
     <label style="display:block">Name:</label>
     <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="firstname" style="display:block"/>
  
     <label for="" style="display:block">E-mail</label>
     <input class="contakt-input" type="text" name="secondname" style="display:block"/>
 </form>

Comment: You should make an edit to your post and put that in.

Answer (score 0):

```
label, input {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting

```
label {display: block;}
```

it works for me

```
input {display: block;}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this css property in form element

```
  display: table-caption;
```